# Eclipse4 RCP Standalone Product : Class Not Found Expection

Tags: eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin, export, rcp

I have created two plug-in projects. The first declares my views, I'll call this my component project. The second declares my product, application and perspectives, incorporating various views from my component project, I'll call this my product project. Launching from Eclipse everything works fine, all views display properly, etc. But when I export my product using the Eclipse Product export wizard and launch as a stand-alone application, I get Class Not Found Exceptions for the views declared in my component project.

Doing a little digging I noticed that none of the classes were actually being packaged in the exported component project (plug-in) jar file. I tried all sorts of techniques to fix this issue, but to no avail.

**In short:** How do I get the plug-in jar file to include java classes declared within the plug-in (i.e. views and other implementation files)?

(Eclipse 4)

Comment: I included the /target/classes/ directory in the build, this brings the .class files into the plug-in properly; but the stand-alone execution still gives ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first clean and re-build your projects.
Most of those problems caused by plug-in build.Check your `build.properties` file.
A standard `build.properties` file may looks like:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
           META-INF/,\
           .,\
           icons/
```

Be sure not to miss any imported jar files.
You can get more info from [link1](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/manifest_editor/build.htm) and [link2](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/reference/pde_feature_generating_build.htm)

Comment: Why do you include "."? Seems like over kill.

Comment: Hay sweet the "." fixed it! Got the class files with them being in /target/classes/